# How to set the transparency key on a PowerPoint window?

Tags: c#, powerpoint, user32

I am trying to create an application which is able to switch between multiple PowerPoint presentations and also movies etc. The interface of this program is running on the primary monitor and powerpoint would be on the secondary monitor. To control powerpoint I am using the powerpoint automation library.

Since it is necessary that the presentations are continuing while the powerpoint window doesn't have the focus I am using the "Browsed by an individual" slide show setting. To ensure that only the slide show is visible on the monitor I am using the SetParent function from the user32 library. This part of the program works fine. However I also want to be able to set a transparent color to the powerpoint window, this to make it possible to have for instance some text in the presentation as subtitles.

To set a transparent color I use the SetLayeredWindowAttributes function also from the user32 library. But it seems that powerpoint has problems handling a transparency key. When testing my program I noticed that setting the transparency key with and without aero enabled changes the symptoms of the issue, but in both modes it is not possible to set the transparency key properly. The description below assumes aero is enabled.

During testing I also observed that when using the Spy++ utility that when I hovered the finder tool above the powerpoint window that suddenly the first slide of the presentation becomes visible and transparent with the correct transparent color. However, when changing the slide this effect is gone and when reusing the finder tool the first slide becomes transparent and visible again, even when the actual selected slide is not the first slide.

To resolve this issue I tried to remove the `CS_OWNDC` window class style from the powerpoint window since that class style is not compatible with the `WS_EX_LAYERED` window style according to the documentation (I was able to remove this class by injecting code into the powerpoint process which calls the SetClassLongPtr function). However that got me stuck with a blue screen of death when exiting my application (when my application was still running I did not notice any difference with or without the `CS_OWNDC` window class).

To make sure that all the calls to `SetParent` etc. are not part of the problem I stripped down my code to the following:

```
private static void SetWindowTransparencyKey(IntPtr HWND, COLORREF TransparentColor)
{
   // Add WS_EX_LAYERED to the window style
   uint OldWindowStyle = (uint)GetWindowLongPtr(HWND, (int)GWL.GWL_EXSTYLE);
   uint NewWindowStyle = OldWindowStyle | (uint)WindowStyles.WS_EX_LAYERED;
   SetWindowLongPtr(HWND, (int)GWL.GWL_EXSTYLE, (IntPtr)NewWindowStyle);

   // Set the transparent color
   SetLayeredWindowAttributes(HWND, TransparentColor.ColorDWORD, 255, LWA_COLORKEY);
}
```

When I use this code directly on the main window of a manually opened powerpoint instance running in the "browsed by an individual" mode all the observations stated above stay the same. This means that somehow there is something very strange happening within powerpoint which is able to disable the transparency key. Interesting is that when exiting the "browsed by an individual" mode and returning to the edit mode the transprancy key suddenly is working.

So basically my question boils down to what I can do to get a transparency key working on a powerpoint window running in "browsed by an individual" mode.